Filtering Checkbox Lists based on other Checkbox Lists
I have 6 checkbox lists to select brand, collection, product, subcategory, finish and stock status. I would like to constrain these checkbox lists based on selections in the other checkbox lists. For example, if someone selects an option from brand, then the 5 other checkbox lists will be updated to only display options that match that brand. This is not linear, so users should be able to start with any checkbox list, and should allow multiple selections across checkbox lists.
Here is what I have so far (just showing two of them since they are all similar). The issue I am having is that any selection causes all checkbox lists to be greyed out.
protected void CheckBoxListBrand_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LabBrand.Text = "";
    FilterCheckBoxLists();
    String whereis = " (Table.Vendor = '";
    CheckBoxList ckl = (CheckBoxList)sender;
    Boolean first = true;
    Boolean somechecked = false;
    selectionbrand.Text = "";

    foreach (ListItem li in ckl.Items)
    {
        if (li.Selected == true)
        {
            if (first)
            {
                whereis += li.Value;
                first = false;
            }
            else
            {
                whereis += "') OR (Table.Vendor = '" + li.Value;
            }
            selectionbrand.Text += " " + li.Text;
            somechecked = true;
        }
    }
    whereis += "')";
    if (somechecked)
    {
        LabBrand.Text += whereis;
    }

    Updatepage();
}

protected void CheckBoxListBrand_Set()
{
    LabBrand.Text = "";
    FilterCheckBoxLists();
    String whereis = " (Table.Vendor = '";
    CheckBoxList ckl = CheckBoxListBrand;
    Boolean first = true;
    Boolean somechecked = false;
    foreach (ListItem li in ckl.Items)
    {
        if (li.Selected == true)
        {
            if (first)
            {
                whereis += li.Value;
                first = false;
            }
            else
            {
                whereis += "') OR (Table.Vendor = '" + li.Value;
            }
            somechecked = true;
        }
    }
    whereis += "')";
    if (somechecked)
    {
        LabBrand.Text += whereis;
    }
}

protected void CheckBoxListCollection_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LabCollection.Text = "";
    FilterCheckBoxLists();
    String whereis = " (Table.Collection = '";
    CheckBoxList ckl = (CheckBoxList)sender;
    Boolean first = true;
    Boolean somechecked = false;
    selectioncollection.Text = "";
    foreach (ListItem li in ckl.Items)
    {
        if (li.Selected == true)
        {
            if (first)
            {
                whereis += li.Value;
                first = false;
            }
            else
            {
                whereis += "') OR (Table.Collection = '" + li.Value;
            }
            selectioncollection.Text += " " + li.Text;
            somechecked = true;
        }
    }
    whereis += "')";
    if (somechecked)
    {
        LabCollection.Text += whereis;
    }
    Updatepage();
}

protected void CheckBoxListCollection_Set()
{
    LabCollection.Text = "";
    FilterCheckBoxLists();
    String whereis = " (Table.Collection = '";
    CheckBoxList ckl = CheckBoxListCollection;
    Boolean first = true;
    Boolean somechecked = false;
    foreach (ListItem li in ckl.Items)
    {
        if (li.Selected == true)
        {
            if (first)
            {
                whereis += li.Value;
                first = false;
            }
            else
            {
                whereis += "') OR (Table.Collection = '" + li.Value;
            }
            somechecked = true;
        }
    }
    whereis += "')";
    if (somechecked)
    {
        LabCollection.Text += whereis;
    }
}
    


private void FilterCheckBoxLists()
    {
        var selectedBrands = GetSelectedValues(CheckBoxListBrand);
        var selectedCollections = GetSelectedValues(CheckBoxListCollection);

        FilterBrands(selectedCollections, selectedProducts, selectedSubCats, selectedFinishes, selectedStocks);
        FilterCollections(selectedBrands, selectedProducts, selectedSubCats, selectedFinishes, selectedStocks);
}

private List<string> GetSelectedValues(CheckBoxList checkBoxList)
{
    return checkBoxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
        .Where(li => li.Selected)
        .Select(li => li.Value)
        .ToList();
}

private void FilterBrands(List<string> selectedCollections, List<string> selectedProducts, List<string> selectedSubCats, List<string> selectedFinishes, List<string> selectedStocks)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxListBrand.Items)
    {
        item.Enabled = true;
    }

    if (selectedCollections.Any() || selectedProducts.Any() || selectedSubCats.Any() || selectedFinishes.Any() || selectedStocks.Any())
    {
        foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxListBrand.Items)
        {
            item.Enabled = IsBrandRelated(selectedCollections, selectedProducts, selectedSubCats, selectedFinishes, selectedStocks, item.Value);
        }
    }
}

private void FilterCollections(List<string> selectedBrands, List<string> selectedProducts, List<string> selectedSubCats, List<string> selectedFinishes, List<string> selectedStocks)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxListCollection.Items)
    {
        item.Enabled = true;
    }
    if (selectedBrands.Any() || selectedProducts.Any() || selectedSubCats.Any() || selectedFinishes.Any() || selectedStocks.Any())
    {
        foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxListCollection.Items)
        {
            item.Enabled = IsBrandRelated(selectedBrands, selectedProducts, selectedSubCats, selectedFinishes, selectedStocks, item.Value);
        }
    }
}
private bool IsBrandRelated(List<string> selectedCollections, List<string> selectedProducts, List<string> selectedSubCats, List<string> selectedFinishes, List<string> selectedStocks, string brandValue)
{
    return
        selectedCollections.Any(collection =>
        IsCollectionForBrand(collection, brandValue)) ||

        selectedProducts.Any(product =>
        IsProductForBrand(product, brandValue)) ||

        selectedSubCats.Any(subcat =>
        IsSubCatForBrand(subcat, brandValue)) ||

        selectedFinishes.Any(finish =>
        IsFinishForBrand(finish, brandValue)) ||

        selectedStocks.Any(stock =>
        IsStockForBrand(stock, brandValue));
}

private bool IsCollectionRelated(List<string> selectedBrands, List<string> selectedProducts, List<string> selectedSubCats, List<string> selectedFinishes, List<string> selectedStocks, string collectionValue)
{
    return
        selectedBrands.Any(brand =>
        IsBrandForCollection(brand, collectionValue)) ||

        selectedProducts.Any(product =>
        IsProductForCollection(product, collectionValue)) ||

        selectedSubCats.Any(subcat =>
        IsSubCatForCollection(subcat, collectionValue)) ||

        selectedFinishes.Any(finish =>
        IsFinishForCollection(finish, collectionValue)) ||

        selectedStocks.Any(stock =>
        IsStockForCollection(stock, collectionValue));
}
    //checking CBLs against selected Brand
private bool IsCollectionForBrand(string collection, string brand)
{
    return ExecuteQuery($"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE Collection = '{collection}' AND Vendor = '{brand}'") > 0;
}
private bool IsProductForBrand(string product, string brand)
{
    return ExecuteQuery($"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE Product = '{product}' AND Vendor = '{brand}'") > 0;
}
private bool IsSubCatForBrand(string subcat, string brand)
{
    return ExecuteQuery($"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE SubCategory = '{subcat}' AND Vendor = '{brand}'") > 0;
}
private bool IsFinishForBrand(string finish, string brand)
{
    return ExecuteQuery($"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE Finish = '{finish}' AND Vendor = '{brand}'") > 0;
}
private bool IsStockForBrand(string stock, string brand)
{
    return ExecuteQuery($"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE Stock = '{stock}' AND Vendor = '{brand}'") > 0;
}

(***SIMILAR CODE TO CHECK CBLs AGAINST SELECTED COLLECTIONS***)

private int ExecuteQuery(string query)
{
    int count = 0;


    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            count = (int)command.ExecuteScalar(); 
        }
    }

    return count;
}

and the .aspx
<h3 id="brandheader" class="NavHeader">Brand</h3>
<div id="brandoptionsCBL" class="subnav">
        <asp:CheckBoxList id="CheckBoxListBrand" CssClass="CBL" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlTableVendor" DataTextField="Vendor" DataValueField="Vendor" RepeatColumns="1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxListBrand_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:CheckBoxList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" id="SqlTableVendor" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Vendor] FROM [Table] WHERE [Vendor] <> '' ORDER BY [Vendor]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>

<h3 id="collectionheader" class="NavHeader">Collection</h3>
<div id="collectionoptionsCBL" class="subnav">
        <asp:CheckBoxList id="CheckBoxListCollection" CssClass="CBL" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlTableCollection" DataTextField="Collection" DataValueField="Collection" RepeatColumns="1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxListCollection_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:CheckBoxList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" id="SqlTableCollection" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Collection] FROM [Table] WHERE [Collection] <> '' ORDER BY [Collection]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>


Checkbox lists are greyed out after selection because the enabled/disabled state of the items isn’t properly reset before applying filters. Besides that, code duplication and performance issues, this might be vulnerable to SQL injection.
